# Tell AutoMapper that a field is a top-level member

Tags: automapper, entity-framework-core, iqueryable

I am trying to take some of the pain out of creating mapping expressions in AutoMapper, using AutoMapper.QueryableExtensions

I have the following, which gives a critical performance gain:

```
    private MapperConfiguration CreateConfiguration() {
        return new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<Widget, WidgetNameDto>()
        .ForMember(dto => dto.Name,
            conf => conf.MapFrom(w => w.Name)));
    }
```

To understand the performance gain, see here: https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/blob/master/docs/Queryable-Extensions.md The key is that the query is limited by field at the database level.

It's terrific that this works. But I anticipate needing to do a lot of this kind of projecting. I am trying to take some of the pain out of the syntax in the ForMember clause above.

For example, I've tried this:

```
    public static IMappingExpression<TFrom, TTo> AddProjection<TFrom, TTo, TField>(this IMappingExpression<TFrom, TTo> expression,
        Func<TFrom, TField> from,
        Func<TTo, TField> to
        )
        => expression.ForMember(t => to(t), conf => conf.MapFrom(f => from(f)));
```

The problem is that everything I do runs into an error:

```
AutoMapper.AutoMapperConfigurationException : Custom configuration for members is only supported for top-level individual members on a type.
```

Even if the passed in Funcs are top-level individual members, that fact is lost in the passing, so I hit the error. I've also tried changing Func<Whatever> to Expression<Func<Whatever>>. It doesn't help.

Is there any way I can simplify the syntax of the ForMember clause? Ideally, I would just pass in the two relevant fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, there is no need to add mapping for the fields/properties that match by name - AutoMapper maps them automatically by convention (that's why it is called *convention-based object-object mapper*). And for including just some of the properties in the projection you could use the [Explicit expansion](http://automapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Queryable-Extensions.html#explicit-expansion) feature.

Second, what you call a *pain in the `ForMember` syntax* is in fact a flexibility. For instance, the explicit expansion and other behaviors can be controlled by `conf` argument, so it's not only for specifying the source.

With that being said, what you ask is possible. You have to change the `from`/ `to` type to `Expression`:

```
 Expression<Func<TFrom, TField>> from,
 Expression<Func<TTo, TField>> to
```

and the implementation simply as follows:

```
=> expression.ForMember(to, conf => conf.MapFrom(from));
```